# How do you describe a convex hull for the set of points in $y = \sin x$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

More specifically in, the set notation for the original set is:
$$ 
    S =  \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  x\\ y\\ \end{bmatrix} : y = \sin x \end{Bmatrix}
$$

So, how would you find the convex hull for this set and write it the same way as the original set?

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram of $S$ and tried to sketch what the complex hull looks like it ought to be?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well, I know that it is a sine curve with $ x \in \left(-\infty, \infty\right) $ and $ y \in \left(-1, 1\right) $

Comment: Then what about $\mathbb{R}\times[-1,1]$ for the interior of the hull and $\mathbb{R}\times\{-1,1\}$ for its boundary ?

Comment: @icanc: You don't always have $y\in(-1,1)$. Consider, for example, $x=\pi/2$...

Comment: @VincentNivoliers I don't understand what you mean.  But I do realize that it should be $ \left[-1, 1\right] $ instead because -1 and 1 are included in that interval.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, I realize that the interval should be closed.  I havn't made the edit.

Comment: @icanc $\mathbb{R}\times[-1,1]$ expands to $\{(x,y) : x\in \mathbb{R} \mbox{ and } y \in [-1,1] \}$ which is the smallest convex set wrt. inclusion containing $S$. $\times$ is the [cartesian product between sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Comment: @VincentNivoliers Oh ok, thank you. I was unfamiliar with that notation.

Comment: I still have no clue on how you would find the convex hull.

Comment: You should prove that $\mathbb{R}\times[-1,1]$ is convex, and that any convex set containing $S$ contains this set. For the first one, prove that any point on a segment between two points of $\mathbb{R}\times[-1,1]$ is in $\mathbb{R}\times[-1,1]$, for the second one, prove that any convex set containing $S$ contains the lines $\mathbb{R}\times\{1\}$ and $\mathbb{R}\times\{-1\}$, and therefore all the points in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the points where $x\in X_1=\{(4k+1)\pi/2:\ k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. For any $x\in X_1$, $\sin x=1$. Now consider any $t\in \mathbb R$; there exists $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $(4k+1)\pi/2\leq t<(4(k+1)+1)\pi/2$. Then there exist $\alpha\in[0,1]$ with $t=\alpha(4k+1)\pi/2+(1-\alpha)(4(k+1)+1)\pi/2$. Thus
$$
\begin{bmatrix}t\\1\end{bmatrix}=\alpha\begin{bmatrix}(4k+1)\pi/2\\1\end{bmatrix}+(1-\alpha)\begin{bmatrix}(4(k+1)+1)\pi/2\\1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This shows that $\begin{bmatrix}t\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is in the convex hull of $S$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$ (i.e. the whole line $y=1$ is).

Similarly, working with the numbers $(4k+3)\pi/2$ we get that $\begin{bmatrix}t\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ is in the convex hull for all $t$.

Now take $x\in\mathbb R$, $y\in[-1,1]$. Then there exists $\alpha\in[0,1]$ such that $y=\alpha\,1+(1-\alpha)(-1)$. Then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}=\alpha\begin{bmatrix}x\\1\end{bmatrix}+(1-\alpha)\begin{bmatrix}x\\-1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

In other words, 
$$
\text{conv}\,S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}:\ x\in\mathbb R,\ y\in[-1,1]\right\}.
$$